# On subgroup assosiated with the non abelian tensor product of groups

Tags: group-theory, gap

‎Let $G$ be a group and $Aut(G)$ denote the automorphisms group of $G$‎. ‎Then we define the action $G$ on $Aut(G)$ given by‎
‎$\alpha^{g}=\alpha^{{\phi_{g}}}=\phi_{g}^{-1}\circ\alpha\circ\phi_{g}$ and the action $Aut(G)$ on $G$ given by‎
‎$g^{\alpha}=(g)\alpha$  for all $g \in G$, $\alpha\in Aut(G)$ and $\phi_{g} \in Inn(G)$.

Hence non abelian tensor product $G\otimes Aut(G)$ is defined.

We say a group G is $2_{\otimes}$-auto Engel group if $$[g, \alpha]\otimes\alpha = 1_{\otimes},$$ for all $g \in G$ and $\alpha\in Aut(G)$.

I want some non-trivial examples of $2_{\otimes}$-auto Engel groups.

Thank you

Comment: Could you explain how $[g, \alpha]$ for $g \in G$ and $\alpha\in Aut(G)$ is defined, please.

Comment: $[g,\alpha]=g^{-1}(g)\alpha$

Comment: I am not aware of existing implementations for non-abelian tensor products in GAP 4 - it is better to ask [GAP Forum](http://www.gap-system.org/Contacts/Forum/forum.html) in case anybody knows them. Also, there is a 1998 thesis "The nonabelian tensor product of groups: computations and structural results" by Aidan McDermott supervised by Graham Ellis in Galway. That was implemented in GAP 3, however. Perhaps you may contact them to ask about the current status of that implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there are many possibilities. I would try to think of a group with $\mathbb{Z_{2}}$ center whose automorphism group is also $\mathbb{Z}_{2}$. Maybe some sort of semidirect product?

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of existing implementations for non-abelian tensor products in GAP 4 - it is better to ask [GAP Forum](http://www.gap-system.org/Contacts/Forum/forum.html) in case anybody knows them.

Also, there is a 1998 thesis "The nonabelian tensor product of groups: computations and structural results" by Aidan McDermott supervised by Graham Ellis in Galway. That was implemented in GAP 3, however. Perhaps you may contact them to ask about the current status of that implementation.

(Using my former comment to remove this from the unanswered queue).